# Lisp-like configuration using code in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a raytracer in Haskell and, currently, I define my scene in code like so:

```
(Scene [(Sphere (Vec3 1 0 0) 4 (PhongMaterial (color 1 0 0) (color 1 1 1) 4))]
       [(PhongLight (Vec3 0 0 0) (color 1 1 1) (color 1 1 1))])
```

This works really well in terms of expressivity, and it's great because I don't have to write any sort of parser, but it means that I have to recompile every time I want to render a different scene. I've come to Haskell through Lisp, where this would be simple (load a file, eval the contents and then render the result) but I recognize that Haskell has traits that makes that, if not impossible, then very difficult.

Do any of you much more experienced Haskellers have any suggestions for the best way to go around solving this? In an ideal world, I'd have some file external to my code that defined the scene in Haskell syntax which I could load; in the least-ideal world possible I'd be writing a parser in Parsec. Thanks!

Comment: Can you say a bit more about the `color` function? Generally, Haskell has lots of good libraries for serializing and deserializing data in various ways, but serializing and deserializing code can be a bit more involved. If those calls to `color` can be replaced with the data they produce instead, that makes the situation much easier.

Comment: Is `color 1 1 1` a function call?  Could it be changed to a constructor (so that it's data)?

Comment: Do you want to interpret everything or do you want to compile the renderer and load the scene dynamically?

Comment: The `color` function is currently just a convenience function for a longer, more complex data constructor, but I'd be willing to sacrifice some of the succinctness for a simple solution.

Comment: @HeinrichApfelmus: I want to compile the renderer and load the scene dynamically from the renderer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you make sure all of your `data` are instances of `Read` (... `deriving Read`), then you can just `read them :: Withatypeifnecessary`.

An intermediate solution would be to use [json](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/json/0.4.3/doc/html/Text-JSON.html); parsing is easier than using Parsec, but of course it's a bit harder than just `read`-ing in code.

---

Update:  if there are non-constructor functions, the `read` approach won't work.

Comment: What's your story for the `color 1 0 0` bits, that actually are a call to a (non-constructor) function?

Comment: Two really good options. I think I'll go the Read route for now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In this case, could you simply use `read` (assuming that everything does `deriving Read`).  It's obviously a little clunky but chances are it would probably work (and it's less work than going down the parsec route).

Comment: It does handle extra parentheses. Try it. =)

Answer (score 0):

How about using a haskell interpreter like [Hint](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint)? Admittedly this is not as easy as in lisp and you need to be extra careful that you compile your renderer with the same modules as you use for describing your scenes, but still it could work ok, even though it isn't really a Haskell way of doing things.

```
 main :: IO ()
 main = do 
      [a] <- getArgs
      r <- runInterpreter (loadScene a)
      case r of
        Left err -> printInterpreterError err
        Right scene -> raytrace scene

 loadScene :: Filepath -> Interpreter ()
 loadScene fn = do
      loadModules [fn]
      eval "name_of_variable_describing_scene_in_my_source"
```